# Playbook is unable to read local_facts when facts files created in same playbook

Tags: ansible

**I have simple playbook in which I am trying to push local_fact files to remote hosts and then executing tasks based on comparison of local facts. However facts files are created on remote host as expected but not being read**

I thought there must be delay between file creation and read so I but wait_for to make sure file is created before it being read

```
`- hosts: "{{ target }}"
   vars:
     abc:  "10"
     xyz:  "11"

  tasks:

- name: write custom fact
  copy:
    dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/somefact_b.fact
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
    content: |
      {'some_var1': {{ abc|int }}}

- name: write custom fact
  copy:
    dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/somefact_a.fact
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
    content: |
     {'some_var2': {{ xyz|int }}}

- wait_for:
    path: /etc/ansible/facts.d/somefact_b.fact

- wait_for:
    path: /etc/ansible/facts.d/somefact_a.fact

- debug: var=ansible_local.somefact_a.some_var1

- debug: var=ansible_local.somefact_b.some_var2

- debug:
    msg: "Everything Looks Good"
  when: ansible_local.somefact_a.some_var1 != ansible_local.somefact_b.some_var2`
```

Comment: `{"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_local.somefact_a.some_var1 != ansible_local.somefact_b.some_var2' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_local.somefact_a.some_var1 != ansible_local.somefact_b.some_var2): 'dict object' has no attribute 'somefact_a'\n\nThe error appears to have been in`

Comment: You should call the `setup` module after you created your new facts on the managed hosts. Fact gathering is usually one of the first steps in playbook execution.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Not being read at the first time if the same playbook is re-ran it works fine."*

A: Start new play inside the same playbook.

```
- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  vars:
    abc:  "10"
    xyz:  "11"
  tasks:
    - name: write custom fact
      copy:
        ...

- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_local.somefact_a.some_var1
    - debug: var=ansible_local.somefact_b.some_var2
      ...
```

For example the playbook below

```
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/somefact_a.fact
        content: |
          {"some_var1": 10}

- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_local.somefact_a.some_var1
```

gives

```
ok: [test_01] => {
    "ansible_local.somefact_a.some_var1": "10"
}
```

---

Notes

1) *setup* is needed to read the variables

```
$ ansible -i hosts test_01 -m setup -a "filter=ansible_local"
test_01 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_local": {
            "somefact_a": {
                "some_var1": 10
            }
        }
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
```

2) Without *setup* the variables are not available

```
$ ansible -i hosts test_01 -m debug -a "var=ansible_local"
test_01 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_local": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

3) The same negative result can be achieved with *`gather_facts: false`*

```
- hosts: test_01
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_local.somefact_a.some_var1
```

Comment: No luck with above -

Comment: Not sure if this is bug but I have reported this https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/63043

Comment: Works for me. I've updated the answer with the example.

Comment: You should close the issue. "setup" is needed to read the variables.